# Python - Get dimension from a rectangle on screen

Tags: python, screenshot, draw, dimension

I'm trying to make a programm with python to take screenshots out of a rectangle you draw on your screen, but first, I'd prefer to determine the dimensions. How can I do that? How can I draw a rectangle and then get the size of it? I'm trying to use pyautogui or PILLOW, but I still need practice. I also thought about using tkinter to make a transparent window and then doing it from there, but I can't figure out how to do it on Lubuntu 18.04.

And if you have any other recommendations or advice about the screenshot part, It's welcome!

Hope the problem it's clear, thank you in advance! ;)

Comment: What library are you using to interact with the screen?

Comment: Hi! I heard about pyautogui and PILLOW, but I still need practice with those. Any recommendations about what to choose??

Comment: What did you code so far?

Comment: Hey there! Actually I haven't done much because I'm getting trouble trying to make a transparent window in Lubuntu